# How to locate duplicates citations?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am writing a document that has several hundred references. I am using bibtex data-base to write down these references.

The problem is that I just figured that there are some duplicate references inside the bibtex file. Is there any easy way that I can locate these duplicate references?

Thanks

Comment: Citations using the same bib key, or citations to different bib keys that actually reference the same source text?

Comment: citations to same bibkeys, I guess. What I mean is assume I have two references in my bibtex which are basically the same, but only their name is bibtex name is different.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of external programs to maintain a .bib file, including a option to search and handle duplicates. I use KBibTex under linux, but there is a [Windows file](http://home.gna.org/kbibtex/download.html) too (if you use Windows).